# how to get difference of 2 columns in dynamically created rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, difference, array-difference

I have a dynamically created table having 3 columns. I need the difference of Col 2 and Col 1 to be populated in Col 3. I have no clue as to how to proceed with dynamically created tables. I'm reading the table values in my save function. Can you please suggest as to how to include the code for the difference?

**JS:**

```
function save()
{
 var eval_tbl = document.getElementById('bagger_reading_list');
 var eval_row_array = [];
        for (i=0; i<eval_tbl.rows.length; i++)
        {
            var tableRow = {
                Start_Reading : eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[1].firstElementChild.value,
                End_Reading : eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[2].firstElementChild.value,
                Total_Reading : eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[3].firstElementChild.value, \\ I need the difference of End-Reading - Start_Reading to be displayed on Total_Reading of eah row created.
            }
            eval_row_array[eval_row_array.length] = tableRow;
        }

}
```

Comment: Why not calculate the difference beforehand to avoid DOM traversal. You already have the data you need.

Comment: @aruna Please find the answers below and mark one as accepted that best solves your problem.

Comment: This is a wrong design principle. If you have the data in hand....process it first. Make it in a shape to just render and then it should not require further DOM traversal to just change the data representation. The best way is to keep the data array synced with html....manipulate on the array...and then re-render the html if required.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the values into Float (just to be safe) using `parseFloat()` and add it up. Do it like:

```
Total_Reading : parseFloat(eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[2].firstElementChild.value) - parseFloat(eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[1].firstElementChild.value),
```

So, your save function should look like:

```
function save()
{
 var eval_tbl = document.getElementById('bagger_reading_list');
 var eval_row_array = [];
        for (i=0; i<eval_tbl.rows.length; i++)
        {
            var tableRow = {
                Start_Reading : eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[1].firstElementChild.value,
                End_Reading : eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[2].firstElementChild.value,
                Total_Reading : parseFloat(eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[2].firstElementChild.value) - parseFloat(eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[1].firstElementChild.value)
            }
            eval_row_array[eval_row_array.length] = tableRow;
        }

}
```

Readup: [parseFloat() | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 function save()
    {
     var eval_tbl = document.getElementById('bagger_reading_list');
     var eval_row_array = [];
            for (i=0; i<eval_tbl.rows.length; i++)
            {
var startReading = eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[1].firstElementChild.value;
var endReading = eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[2].firstElementChild.value;
var totalReading = parseFloat(endReading) - parseFloat(startReading);
                var tableRow = {
                    Start_Reading : startReading,
                    End_Reading : endReading,
                    Total_Reading : totalReading
                }
                eval_row_array[eval_row_array.length] = tableRow;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The code provided has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small code. Check if it fits your need

```
 function saved()
{

         var eval_tbl = document.getElementById('Table');
         var eval_row_array = [];
         for (i=0; i<eval_tbl.rows.length; i++)
        {

            var tableRow = {
                Start_Reading : eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML,
                End_Reading : eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML,
                Total_Reading :parseInt(eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML) - parseInt(eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML)
            }
             eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML=parseInt(eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML) - parseInt(eval_tbl.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML)
            eval_row_array[eval_row_array.length] = tableRow;

        }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I have implemented the solution based on the earlier responses. Appreciate the information shared.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine.